# Changing the audio player icon when play ends

Tags: jquery, image, audio, html5-audio

I'm using some code I found on a codepen that style the `audio` tag to use icons.

The originial code only worked with one player, so I've changed to so it works with multiple players on the same page. This works and it does play the correct wav file depending on which icon you click.

My issue is once play back of a specific wav file is complete the icon doesn't return to it's original `play` state.

I've created a **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dsfrm5qa/1/)** here which shows what I mean.

This is the jquery I'm using when play back ends:

```
   $('#player' + id).on('ended', function() {
       console.log ('ended')
     $('#speaker' + id).removeClass('speakerplay');
     /*When the audio has finished playing, remove the class speakerplay*/
     audiostatus = 'off';
     /*Set the status back to off*/
   });
```

I think the issue is due to id not being know or it could be any one of the players ID's

Anyone any idea how I can resolve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've fixed it.

```
 $('[id^="player"]').on('ended', function() {
     id = this.id.replace('player','')
     $('#speaker' + id).removeClass('speakerplay');
     audiostatus = 'off';
 });
```

new **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dsfrm5qa/2/)** showing it working.